# Image is not being added in Cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Crinsane Shopping Cart and I was trying to pass an image to Cart, but 
I am having error

> Argument 5 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in
>   E:\phalwalatheme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 221

**CartController.php**

```
public function addItem($id)
{
     $products=Products::find($id);

     Cart::add($id,$products->name, $products->image ,1,$products->price);
     return back();
}
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
<td class="product-thumbnail">
    <img src="{{url('images/product',$cartItem->image)}}" alt="product-thumbnail">
</td>
```

When I comment `$products->image` everything works fine. And img `div` is also showing "alt" output. I have also used `{{ $product->image}}` and  `array($products->image)`. But none of them worked.

Comment: I think you need to try like this: `Cart::add(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $products->name 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $products->price));` Hope this helps you!!

Comment: But still how do I declare image???

Comment: `Cart::add(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $products->name, 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $products->price, 'image' => $products->image));` Try this, may be work!

Comment: Yep I have done no error but still image is not being displayed.

Comment: In your blade file, it's not displayed?

Comment: I have displayed its code is also written above.

Comment: Try like: `<img src="/images/product/{{ $cartItem['image']; }}" alt="product-thumbnail">`

Comment: Nope getting error Cannot use object of type Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem as array

Comment: Try this: `<img src="/images/product/{{ $cartItem->image }}" alt="product-thumbnail">`

Comment: No error but no image displayed.

Comment: Where is your image stored? can you please give path?

Comment: E:\phalwalatheme\public\images\product

Comment: Try: `<img src="{{ asset('images/product/'.$cartItem->image) }}" alt="product-thumbnail">`

Comment: Still a problem. I have tried  ` <img src="{{url('images/product/',$cartItem->image )}}" alt="product-thumbnail">` but no

Comment: Try my answer's `src` path plz. Not use `url()` for now!

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: Try to search how to display images from `public` path in laravel. I have fixed your `Argument 5 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() must be of the type array, string given` error. Thanks!

Comment: Your are welcome

Comment: Upvote if this fixed your issue reagaring `Argument 5 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() must be of the type array, string given`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is saying that `Argument 5 passed to Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() must be of the type array, string given` That means it need `array()` and you give `string`.

Try like below:

```
Cart::add(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $products->name, 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $products->price, 'image' => $products->image));
```

To display image in your `cart.blade.php` file, do like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/product/'. $cartItem->image) }}" alt="product-thumbnail">
```

Hope this fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You should use array() like:

#### CartController.php

```
public function addItem($id){
    $products=Products::find($id);

    Cart::add(array('id' => $id, 'name' => $products->name, 'qty' => 1, 
    'price' => $products->price, 'image' => $products->image));

    return back();
}
```

#### cart.blade.php

```
<td class="product-thumbnail">
    <img src="/images/product/{{$cartItem->image}}" alt="product-thumbnail">
</td>
```

make sure `$cartItem->image` is a link to an image resource
url second parameter is an array containing a value e.g `url('user/profile', [1]);` read about url helpers in [laravel url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not go through [Crinsane shopping Cart document](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#usage) properly

In its most basic form you can specify the id, name, quantity, price of the product you'd like to add to the cart.

`Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);`

As an optional fifth parameter you can pass it options, so you can add multiple items with the same id, but with (for instance) a different size.

`Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99, ['size' => 'large']);`

so your code should be like this:

`Cart::add($id,$products->name,1,$products->price,['image' => $products->image]);`

Hope this will help.